# Mysql error: Deadlock found when trying to get lock

Tags: php, mysql

I keep getting the deadlock error - Mysql error: `Deadlock found when trying to get lock when updating products`.

I did not write the sql statement and to me it's a mess. Writing a new app but need to fix this until then.  I added - INTERVAL 900 SECOND order by id. The deadlock doesn't appear but now it doesn't update the products. Can someone show a better solution or show me why it's not updating?

```
$sql = "UPDATE  `"
```

Comment: You just randomly added `- INTERVAL 900 SECOND`? This query should generate a syntax error, and would explain why you don't get any deadlocks from it, but no updates either - because the query just isn't executed anymore. A deadlock happens because of another query/client that tries to do something at the same time. Try `SHOW INNODB STATUS` to check which queries collide and maybe post it. Read [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-deadlocks.html) for some ideas on how to fix it. You might get lucky, but preventing deadlocks (or handling them correctly) can be a hard task.

Comment: I just saw that question. There it is valid because it's added after a `now()`. It makes zero sense in your query. If you know how deadlocks work, you might be happy with my link, your question provides no possibility to answer the 1st part of your question ("Can someone show a better solution") any better because one query alone cannot make a deadlock (your mentioned question has 3 queries), and the 2nd part ("or show me why it's not updating?") is already answered by: "because it generates a syntax error" (not because it's too complicated for me). Anyway, I'm outta here. Good luck.